# SQL Searching by MAX()

Tags: sql

`select max(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP) from DOCUMENTS;` will return the time that the latest document was delivered. How do I return **the other columns** for the latest document? For example I want `DOC_NAME` for the document that was most recently delivered?

I'm not sure how to form the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options

```
SELECT DOC_NAME
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP IN (
    SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP)
    FROM DOCUMENTS
)
```

Or with joins

```
SELECT DOC_NAME
FROM DOCUMENTS
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP
    FROM DOCUMENTS
) AS M
    ON M.MAX_DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP = DOCUMENTS.DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP
```

It gets more complicated if there are duplicates in a timestamp or you need multiple columns in your "max" criteria (because `MAX()` is only over the one column for all rows)

This is where the `JOIN` option is the only option available, because a construction like this is not available (say multiple orders with identical timestamp):

```
SELECT DOC_NAME
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE (DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP, ORDERID) IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP, ORDERID
    FROM DOCUMENTS
    ORDER BY DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP DESC, ORDERID DESC
)
```

Where you in fact, would need to do:

```
SELECT DOC_NAME
FROM DOCUMENTS
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP, ORDERID
    FROM DOCUMENTS
    ORDER BY DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP DESC, ORDERID DESC
) AS M
    ON M.DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP = DOCUMENTS.DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP
        AND M.ORDERID = DOCUMENTS.ORDERID
```

Comment: Cade, I was going to reply with the JOIN solution, and then I inspected the execution plan for each technique.  Sql Server 2005 (the db I have handy) uses the same execution plan for each syntax.

So Paul, you have your choice of either... and performance will not suffer

Comment: Yes, the optimizer in SQL Server is very good.  I will modify my answer to note that the JOIN solution is the only one which works when you are dealing with a MAX tuple.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP,
  OTHER_COLUMN
FROM
  DOCUMENTS
WHERE
  DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP) FROM DOCUMENTS)
```

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL, the following works too:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DOCUMENTS ORDER BY DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

On some versions of SQL (i.e. MySQL) you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCUMENTS
ORDER BY DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns all the documents. I only want the most recent document.

Comment: @Paul: The query has the "LIMIT" clause. It will never return more than one record. The returned record is the one with the max value for 'DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP' (the recent document that you want)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Max(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP), 
       Doc_Name
From TableName
Group By Doc_Name
```

That should do it, unless I missed something in the question.

Comment: I don't know of any SQL variant where this is guaranteed to work, and at least on Oracle it certainly won't.

Comment: This works only if you order BY MAX(DELIVERY_TIMESTAMP) and take TOP 1.